# Is it possible to add a Load Balancer to an Existing AWS Elastic Beanstalk app that doesn't have a load balancer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, load-balancing

As the title says, I chose to not use a load balancer, but for SSL support, you need a Load balancer. Is it possible to add a load balancer to my Elastic Beanstalk App? Or will I have to reconfigure a brand new app?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can add load balancer at any time if you have single-instance environment. No need to create new-environment.

In console, to do this, you go to `Configuration->Capacity`:

[image]

Once the load balancer is setup by EB you can proceed with setting up your SSL certificate from ACM.

> for SSL support, you need a Load balancer

Technically, you don't need the LB for SSL. But its the easiest way (not the cheapest) to setup one on AWS with ACM.